# Invalid column name "USER_SOURCE"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a stored procedure which is returning a result in an xml `@Data` output parameter

To assign data in xml code is

```
SELECT @data= (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        CONVERT(varchar(2),u.USER_SOURCE ) + '~' + 
        CONVERT(varchar(20), u.[USER_ID]) + '-' +
        CONVERT(varchar(10), u.DEALER_ID) as USER_DEALER_ID
    FROM #users u FOR XML RAW('users'))
```

When I exec the procedure in SQL Server Mgmt Studio, I can see the result OK.

This procedure is been called from another procedure, and that parent procedure is used in SSRS.

In SSRS I am getting error

> Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'.  Invalid column name
>   'USER_SOURCE'. Invalid column name 'USER_ID'. Invalid column name
>   'DEALER_ID'.

Could you please help?

Thanks,
Chetan

Comment: Can you post the code for the calling store procedure?

Comment: If I run procedure from sql server management studio, and then only refresh the dataset in SSRS, Issue gets resolved.

Comment: Thanks Amar,I have added procedure code in question itself

Comment: May be the temp tables created cause this issue.

Comment: Be more consistent in putting square brackets around column and table names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a script which I think reproduces a problem identical to yours:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestTmpTable
  @value varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
  CREATE TABLE #test (id int IDENTITY, value varchar(20));
  INSERT INTO #test (value) VALUES (@value)
  SELECT * FROM #test;
  DROP TABLE #test;
END

GO

CREATE TABLE #test (id int IDENTITY, value2 varchar(20));
EXEC TestTmpTable 'some text';
SELECT * FROM #test;
DROP TABLE #test;

GO

DROP PROCEDURE TestTmpTable
```

As you can see, there are two `#test` tables here, one is created in the stored procedure, the other one in the batch that invokes the stored procedure. They have different structures: one has a column named `value`, the other a column named `value2`. If you run the script, you'll see this error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TestTmpTable, Line 6
Invalid column name 'value'.
```

I can't point you to a relevant documentation article at the moment, but to me it is evident enough that some preliminary name checking is taking place immediately before the execution of the SP. At that stage, a discrepancy between the column names referenced in the stored procedure and those actually present in *the already existing table* is revealed, which renders the execution impossible.

If you change `value2` to `value`, the script will work without any problem, and there will be two row sets in the output, one with the `'some text'` value, the other empty. And of course the script will work if you remove all parts related to the external `#test` table.

So, check the places where your procedure is called to see if any other `#users` table can be existing by that moment, and if so, amend the issue according to your situation.

Comment: Thanks Andriy for detail explanation. I will take a look in my both procedures.

Comment: It works for me. I had two tables #Users one is in parent and one is in child procedures. I rename one from child procedure and it works for me.

Thank you once again :D