# Invalid Column name error in SSRS 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am having an issue with SSRS 2005. I have a case statement that that works fine in other queries and reports, but errors on the latest report for some reason. I don't believe its an issue with the query rather an issue with reporting services. The error I get is "Query execution failed for data set, invalid column name 'Status'.Has anyone else run into this issue? how did you resolve? The code is below just in case

```
    SELECT Task
         , Account_Num
         , CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),Due_Date) < 0
                THEN 'Overdue'
                WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),Due_Date) < 3
                THEN 'Alert'
                ELSE 'Okay'
            END AS Status
       FROM MyDb
```

Comment: perhaps it needs to be escaped using [status]

Comment: It may help to mention that I'm working remotely on the VPN. It shouldn't make a difference, but who knows.

Comment: Check out question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788980/invalid-column-name-user-source.  Might be related...

Answer (score 2):

Try square brackets around the reserved word [status]

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this as well. Other reports have worked using this query without the brackets so I'm not sure if that is the case. @xQbert,

Comment: Try changing the alias to [AccountStatus] instead of [Status]. SSRS uses a stack of technologies that run before and after the query. These technologies can vary, greatly, depending on the contents of each report. Just because "it works in other reports", only means you dodged the error up-to-now. This report says it is choking on the column named "Status". It is a reserved word in many technologies.  Sometimes, you can get it to work, but it is usually best to just avoid reserved words like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this is due to using an alias.  Sometimes, one is not allowed to use the alias and must type out the **fully-qualified name**.

```
ourDatabase.ourTable.ourColumnName
```

This may or may not apply to the OP's situation, however.  I have not tried it with the Case statement.