# Adding a field to a view that is used in a report, causes an error

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report that uses a view. I altered the view so that it would pull a new field. The join for that field was already done. We just hadn't specified that this field should be shown through the view. So I added it and the SQL worked fine.

I selected the new field in VS and ran it. It ran, but showed **#Error** on that field. So I uploaded it to SSRS and got the following error:

[image]

It's telling me the column name is invalid. However, the view works fine in SSMS and VS recognizes the field exists, or it wouldn't have let me set it in the column.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

**More Info**

This report has 4 datasets. I found out that if I only add the AgreedToShipDate field to 1 of the datasets, it doesn't appear in the field list even after using **Refresh Fields**. I also removed the old field, EstimatedShipDate. Now AgreedToShipDate is not throwing an error in VisualStudio. However, the data it's showing for AgreedToShipDate, is actually the data for the old field, EstimatedShipDate. When I publish the report, it gives me the original error.

Comment: So, just to clarify, is `AgreedToShipDate` one of the columns returned by your view when you query it in SSMS?

Comment: @DMason That's correct. That's the new field.

Comment: Please, Look into your query and scan the field names to make sure you have not accidentally used the field AgreedToShipDate more than once in the final output.

Comment: The answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788980/invalid-column-name-user-source) may help

Comment: @lrb I posted a screenshot of the query. It only has AgreedToShipDate once.

Comment: @ChrisLätta Was the answer deleted?

Comment: @ernest No, the answer is there and is accepted. Scroll down maybe?

Comment: @ChrisLätta Oh. I didn't realize there was a link in your reply. I'll take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your framework does some "select *" somewhere in the process.
Apply one time only a sp_refreshview against your view.
Have a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx

Comment: Maybe. I tried calling refresh, but it didn't work. Is there a certain way I need to run it? I just ran it on SSMS. But, the data was already showing up correctly in SSMS. Alos, I updated the post with additional info.

Comment: After reading your last info: try a brute force solution: create a new view identical with this one and refer it in your queries.

Comment: Maybe the refresh took a few minutes to process? It's working now. It's showing the correct data and it publishes correctly.